# How can I generate multiple recolored versions of the same image?

Tags: color, script

Here's the scenario that I'm dealing with:

I have a sticker which I would like to have colored into multiple colors, however, instead of saving each possible (usable) color, I would like to be able to insert the colors that I would want, along with typical or common colors any paint program palette.

Is there a script that I could run, plugin that I could use, or way in which I can generate differently colored clones of the photo?

Comment: Hi user2399528, which image editing program are you trying to run the script in?

Comment: I actually don't know where to start, but I've been using Paint.NET. I could install gimp, and do have PS elements.

Comment: So the artwork you're working with is raster images (jpg, png) and not vector (eps, svg)?

Comment: Correct. It's a/in png.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy answer to your question without seeing the image. It might be trivial or it might be really hard. It would be so much better if your image would have been vector to begin with.

In anycase given the realy vague requirements  would suggest using imagemagick, its free and easy to batch. There are a ton of examples around the net. (start by reading few chapters [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_basics/#replace))

Failing this consider using gimp.